# Why is our Non-Mapped Virtual memory usage high when running MongoDB (MMAP) on CENTOS

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.0

Our non-virtual virtual memory usage on our Linux MongoDb instances seems high, currently sitting just over 2GB. The instances are running a minimal installation of CENTOS (no GUI) and they acting as database servers, nothing else. We also have a Windows machine in the same replica set and that has considerably lower non-mapped virtual memory usage (210MB).

One suggestion from the MMS site is that lots of connections can cause this problem but both Linux machines only have about 16 connections. Can anyone explain what else might cause this high memory usage?

Comment: Each database connection (active or idle) is allocated 1MB of RAM. Other reasons for increased non-mapped virtual memory usage are server-side processing (JavaScript, Map/Reduce, aggregation, in-memory sorts, ...). What is the role of the Linux machines as compared to the Windows machine in your replica set (i.e. primary vs secondary)? Are you doing secondary reads (default is all reads/writes directed to the primary)?

Comment: Hi Stennie, the Windows machine was a secondary and the Linux boxes are a primary and secondary. It looks like part of the high memory is a symptom of replication. We re-replicated one of the Linux boxes a couple of days ago and the memory usage increases in steps as the DB storage gets larger until replication has finished at which point the memory stays high but constant until the server is rebooted. On a reboot the memory is now around 750 MB (both primary and secondary), which is still high given little is happening, but probably acceptable.